# Unable to access const static members in class

Tags: c++

I have read this document
[Initializing static array of strings (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376264/initializing-static-array-of-strings-c) and tried to test in my  compiler if  everything would be fine here is copy of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class MyClass {
public:
    const  static char* MyClass::enumText[];
    };
const  char* MyClass::enumText={"a","b","c","d"};
int main(){

    std::cout<<MyClass::enumText[0]<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

but here is  mistakes

```
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\class_static\class_static.cpp(9): error C2372: 'enumText' : redefinition; different types of indirection
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\class_static\class_static.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'enumText'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\class_static\class_static.cpp(9): error C2078: too many initializers
```

i am using visual c++ 2010  and why such mistakes what is wrong?please help

Comment: oops  sorry guys  i am tired today  and make such cool mistake    sorry i have missed brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class MyClass
{
public:
    const static char* enumText[];
};
const char* MyClass::enumText[] = {"a","b","c","d"};
int main()
{
    std::cout<<MyClass::enumText[0]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That should be:

```
const  char* MyClass::enumText[]={"a","b","c","d"};
// You forgot these           ^^
```

Comment: Shouldn't this actually be `{'a','b','c','d'};`?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now he wants an array of `char` pointers, not an array of `char`.  I'll leave this up nonetheless in case others are cornfuzed.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `[]` in the definition of the variable: `const  char* MyClass::enumText[]={"a","b","c","d"};`

Answer (score 3):

You missed []. It should be
`const  char* MyClass::enumText[]={"a","b","c","d"};`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the [] on the end of your definition of enumText (right before the ={...).